# Angular UI Route/State design and implementation not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have 3 UI views on a page coded like this:

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div ui-view="nav"></div>

  <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">
   <div ui-view="topbar"></div>
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
  <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
    <div ui-view="footer"></div>
</div>
```

A state/route configured for part of the app looks like this:

```js
angular.module('core').config(['$stateProvider',
  function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('core', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/core',
        views: {
          'nav@': {templateUrl:'modules/core/client/views/partials/nav.view.html'},
          'topbar@': {templateUrl:'modules/core/client/views/partials/topbar.view.html'},
          'footer@': {templateUrl:'modules/core/client/views/partials/footer.view.html'}
        },
        data: {
          roles: ['super', 'admin', 'narc']
        }
      })
      .state('core.settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        views: {
          '': {templateUrl:'modules/narc/client/views/content/canvas.list.view.html'}
        },
        data: {
          roles: ['super', 'admin', 'narc']
        }
      });
  }
]);
```

I have 2 problems I am facing.

1. When the link in navigation is set to ui-sref="core.settings" and
   the link clicked, I see canvas.list.view.html in the resources load,
   but it does not load it into the primary "unnamed" view, I also
   tried this with a named ui-view, and same result.
2. When the same link is clicked, it changes the window.location to the
   the URL stated in the config, but if I refresh the page, it 404s
   because it is referencing a state instead of an actual location...
   if I put manually a #! in front of the URL, it pulls up a blank page
   (with nav, topbar and footer loaded, but no unnamed view loaded.

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out #2 above, by changing

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')`

to

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');`

It allows the urls to actually be copied/pasted/shared and still work as long as authentication is in place...

I figured out #1 as well, the abstract "parent" state needed a template:

`template: '<ui-view/>'`

This made it all work. yes!